# How to write a timer actor in Scala?

Tags: scala, timer, actor

I need an actor to send a message every minute. How do I best achieve this behaviour? I am afraid of using `java.lang.Thread.sleep(long millis)` as a thread can be shared among many actors in Scala, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create an actor with `receiveWithin` to act as the timer.

Answer (score 17):

Or as @Daniel mentioned, here a running example:

```
import scala.actors._
import scala.actors.Actor._

class TimerActor(val timeout: Long,val who: Actor,val reply: Any) extends Actor {
  def act {
    loop {
      reactWithin(timeout) {
        case TIMEOUT => who ! reply
      }
    }
  }
}

val a = actor {
  loop {
    react {
      case x => println(x)
    }
  }
}

val t = new TimerActor(1000, a, "Go for it")

a.start
t.start
```

Comment: Thanks. I've accepted Daniel's answer as he was the first, but I greatly appreciate your effort to illustrate it.

Comment: The code can be used for a one-shot timer as well, but you have to take out the `loop` or your replies will start to pile up.

Comment: in this example, the `reactWithin(timeout)` is only waiting for timeout. if i also put a `case` for a particular message, and there are plenty of messages available, will the TIMEOUT event be generated? when i run the test, i dont see any TIMEOUT. how can an actor receive messages and also self generate TIMER events for self at regular intervals? and i want TIMER messages to be handled on priority. so i cant employ another TIMER actor and send timer events to my actor, as they will be added to tail of MailBox. Is there a way to add TIMER message to head of MailBox?

Comment: @weima You should use the `TimerActor` only for `TIMEOUT` and not receiving other messages. Create a new `TimerActor` **inside** your regular actor with `who` = the outher regular actor and let the regular actor handle the `reply` message every `timeout` millisecs.

Comment: thanks @PeterSchmitz, i created a TimerActor within my actor, but i get an exception "assertion failure: receive from channel belonging to another actor"

Comment: @peterSchmitz i used your code but it give me an error reactWithin and actor is not a member of scala package what should i do

Comment: @RishiDwivedi Perhaps: As of scala 2.10.x the actors library is placed in a separate jar scala-actors.jar. See [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/actors-migration-guide.html) Make sure its on your classpath and you have imported it as seen in my example.

Comment: I would just like to add that another reason you don't want to add additional `case` within `receiveWithin` is because the timeout will not happen within every `timeout`. Another case that you take in could will reset the timeout. So if you want a "pure" timer, you don't want to handle anything but `TIMEOUT`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Akka FSM](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.2/scala/fsm.html) to model an actor that stays `forMax` millis in a waiting state and then sends a message, e.g. by switching to another state while using `onTransition` and staying there for 0 millis to switch back to waiting state. There is a good example at the akka page.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to avoid Akka for this project, I am willing to implement this with ordinary Scala actors.

Answer (score 2):

```
import scala.actors._
class Wakeup[A](millis: Int, who: ReplyReactor, alarm: A) extends Thread {
  val done = new java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean(false)
  override def run {
    while (!done.get()) {
      who ! alarm
      Thread.sleep(millis)
    }
  }
}
case object BEEP {}
val a = new ReplyReactor { def act { loop { react {
  case BEEP => println("Wha?!  "+new java.util.Date)
  case _ =>
}}}}
val b = new Wakeup(60000,a,BEEP)
a.start
```

Why use an actor when a thread is what you want?

```
scala> b.start

scala> Wha?!  Mon Nov 07 18:43:18 EST 2011
Wha?!  Mon Nov 07 18:44:18 EST 2011
Wha?!  Mon Nov 07 18:45:18 EST 2011
Wha?!  Mon Nov 07 18:46:18 EST 2011
Wha?!  Mon Nov 07 18:47:18 EST 2011
Wha?!  Mon Nov 07 18:48:18 EST 2011
Wha?!  Mon Nov 07 18:49:18 EST 2011
Wha?!  Mon Nov 07 18:50:18 EST 2011
Wha?!  Mon Nov 07 18:51:18 EST 2011
Wha?!  Mon Nov 07 18:52:18 EST 2011
```

Comment: Isn't it bad to send a message to an actor from a non-actor? There is a question out there with an answer explaining it generally is.

Comment: @Ivan - It can be fine if the actor knows it can't reply.  Receiving messages is more iffy than sending them.

Comment: Because actors share threads. If you pause a thread You pause all the actors running on it

Comment: @KrzysztofWende - What does that have to do with my answer or Ivan's question?

Comment: @RexKerr Using threads explicitly in actor programming is highly discouraged and considered an anti pattern. Besides that using a thread to just wait for something is really bad for performance.

Comment: @KrzysztofWende - You haven't explained _why_ it is discouraged in _this_ case (what is the problem?), and also sleeping threads do _not_ cause sizable performance problems.  If you said it doesn't scale well I'd agree, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: Well. Yeah. That's my point. It is good if it's used once or twice. But if there are more of those it can cause untraceable problems.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up in creation of dedicated Runnable instance, which keeps sending a message to the target actor. Like

```
case class QueueTick()

class QueueWatcherActor extends Actor {

  override def receive = {
    case QueueTick() => // do it here
  }

}

val ref = ActorSystem("xxx")

val actor = ref.actorOf(Props[QueueWatcherActor])

val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()

executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable {
  def run() {
    actor ! QueueTick()
  }
},1,60,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since scala.actors is now deprecated and being replaced with akka actors (and since there is no react or receiveWithin in akka actors), here is how to do it using akka actors (it's actually less of a 'hack' than using receiveWithin anyways IMHO).

The example below schedule a runnable to be invoked after 5 seconds:

```
import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Scheduler}
import scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

class TimerExample {
def example() = {

    def scheduler: Scheduler = ActorSystem.create("timer-example").scheduler

    val myRunnable = new Runnable {
      override def run(): Unit = {
        println("run invoked")
      }
    }

    println("scheduling...")
    scheduler.scheduleOnce(FiniteDuration(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS),myRunnable)
    Thread.sleep(6000)
    println("should have printed 'run invoked'")
}
```