# Update record perday interval

Tags: mysql, sql, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

i am working on project using scala.I wanna make a method in scala which fetch value from mysql and perform some operation on that and agian insert into mysql,i am able to do that but my problem is that this method call **per day interval**. Is there any method in **scala** which solve this problem or i make **Event Scheduler** in mysql. Can any one solve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Create a Timer specific `Actor` and Schedule it. Link to [*Working example on SO*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8047026/767881)

Comment: @Ravinder DNA example in given link give me error actor and loop is not a member of scala package

Comment: I am not much aware of scala syntax. And, you can post a comment on the referred answer for clarification.